# Correct Way to Use AJAX to Update Wordpress Database

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using the jQuery's sortable function inside of a Wordpress plugin to allow a user to set the display order of a number of list items. When a user re-orders the items, jquery .ajax() should send a request to a processing script to update the table.

This is the jQuery:

```
jQuery("#sortable").sortable({
    update : function () {
        var serial = jQuery('#sortable').sortable('serialize'); //split up each li into an array item
        jQuery("body").css("cursor", "progress");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "../wp-content/plugins/libhours/includes/_process.php",
            type: "post",
            data: serial,
            success: function(msg){
                jQuery("body").css("cursor", "default");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error updating the table via AJAX.");
                jQuery("body").css("cursor", "default");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

The URL is located and everything works until I get an error from the _process.php file

```
Call to a member function update() on a non-object in ... _process.php
```

I do NOT get this problem if, say, I am accessing the _process.php file via form submission; inserting and updating records work just fine. Here is the update function for reference...

```
function cp_libhours_update_area_order($data) {
  global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

  $i = 1; //our counter to set the rank of each record NOTE: start at 1...0 will be reserved for new entries
  foreach ($data as $area) {
    // Execute statement:
    $update_sql = $wpdb->update($table_prefix . library_areas, 
        array(
            'displayOrder' => $i
        ),
        array(
            'id' => $area
        )
    );
    $i++;
  }
}
if(isset($_POST['area'])) cp_libhours_update_area_order($_POST['area']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way to do an AJAX call in WordPress. You're currently doing a direct AJAX call to the _process.php file. The call will work, but it's not loaded within the WordPress scope. There are 2 solutions:

1) Include wp-load.php inside your _process.php file, or:

2) (the best option) Do it [the WordPress way](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins): define your action with add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' ) and do an AJAX call to Wordpress' admin_ajax file. Have a look at this page for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Perfect. No. 2 is definitely the way to go. Thanks.